Me cuenta el campo vacío como si fuese 0 en where
mi duda es la siguiente, en una consulta, cuando me va a hacer una comparativa del where, si el campo está vacío, y el valor a comparar es 0, me lo toma como igual. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que no ocurra?
La función que pongo a continuación es el equivalente a sql db_num_rows, y funciona perfectamente
$countdbresult = $Func['db_query']('', "
                        SELECT
                            pps.id, pps.boards, pps.member_groups
                        FROM {db_prefix}postprefixes AS pps
                        WHERE top.id_topic = ".$topic['id']." AND pps.member_groups = 0 LIMIT 1");

                        $alfa['landa] = $Func['db_num_rows']($countdbresult);

Pero cuando en la id_group, la id es 0 (como aparece en la consulta de prueba), y el campo está vacío, me lo lee como si fuese igual, y es lo que quiero evitar. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! 0 no es igual a vacia.. estas seguro que es vacio y no 0???

No te das a entender, dices: "Pero cuando en la id_group (EL) id es 0" pero en tu WHERE tienes  WHERE top.id_topic = ".$topic['id']." AND pps.member_groups = 0 ninguno de esos campos es id_group, es más ese campo no aparece en tu query, que quieres que haga SQL en esa caso? Eso es error de capa 8.
